# How to use xlwings or pandas to get all the non-null cell?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

Recently I need to write a python script to find out how many times the specific string occurs in the excel sheet.

I noted that we can use `*xlwings.Range('A1').table.formula*` to achieve this task only if the cells are continuous. If the cells are not continuous how can I accomplish that?

Comment: The title and your question don't match. Do you want to get the non-null cells, or count the times a given string is in the dataframe?

Comment: Do you want to count it in a specific column? or across the entire worksheet?

Comment: @OmerBA accross the entire worksheet. Thanks

Comment: @DeepSpace Yeah, thanks for your reminder. The final goal is to count the times of a given string. But before that I need to select the non-null cell first, right? Or you have another better way to achieve the final goal please kindly let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hacky, but why not.
By the way, I'm assuming you are using python 3.x.

First well create a new boolean dataframe that matches the value you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('path_to_your_excel..')

b = df.applymap(lambda x: x == 'value_you_want_to_find' if isinstance(x, str) else False)
```

and then simply sum all occurences.

```
print(np.count_nonzero(b.values))
```

Comment: You actually don't have to assume Python 3. Python 2 can `print(..)` as well.

Comment: It's regarding the string check. in python 2 i would do isinstance(x, basestring) :)

Comment: Indeed, I missed that `if`

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments, if you already have a dataframe, you can simply use `count` (Note: there **must** be a better way of doing it):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a': ['a'], 'col_b': ['ab'], 'col_c': ['c']})

string_to_search = '^a$' # should actually be a regex, in this example searching for 'a'
print(sum(df[col].str.count(string_to_search).sum() for col in df.columns))
>> 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @DeepSpace. It seems your code dose not work. What is the variable *string_to_search* used for? Since I cannot find this variable invoked in the third line.

Comment: @YusonKong I messed up, sorry. I fixed it.